# How create Authorize for web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I use web api2.

I need check each request for a sessionKey.

I don't undarstand how get this key from url query or json post data.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

//get session key and create user
        }


    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the `System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext`?  It contains just about everything you're looking for.

Comment: It depends on how you are sending it.  Within the actionContext you can get access to the Request property which has both a Headers property if you pass it in the header or Content which is the body of the request.